# Square of the Dirac Delta Shenanigans

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, quantum-field-theory

The following is a purely mathematical problem, but it often arises when dealing with transition probabilities in Quantum Field Theory.

In [QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) the transition probability amplitudes often contain a Dirac delta of the form:

$$\delta (E_f-E_i)$$

but since we have to deal with [Born's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) we are interested in the square of this quantity, and so we must ask ourself what it means to take the square of a Dirac delta. Usually we deal with the problem (to be precise in the context of box quantisation) in the following way:

We write the Dirac delta in Fourier form<sup>1</sup>:

$$\delta (E_f - E_i)=\lim _{T \to +\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int _{-T/2}^{+T/2}e^{i(E_f-E_i)t}dt$$

obtaining:

$$2\pi\delta (E_f - E_i)=\lim _{T \to +\infty}\int _{-T/2}^{+T/2}e^{i(E_f-E_i)t}dt=\lim _{T \to +\infty}\left[\frac{e^{i(E_f-E_i)t}}{i(E_f-E_i)}\right] _{-T/2}^{+T/2}=\lim _{T \to +\infty}\frac{2 \sin(\Delta E T/2)}{\Delta E} \tag{1}$$

From $(1)$ we operate the following magic trick (i.e. abuse): since we want to find the square of the Dirac delta we can think of writing

$$(2\pi)^2\delta ^2(\Delta E)=\lim _{T \to +\infty}\frac{4 \sin^2 (\Delta E T/2)}{(\Delta E)^2} \tag{2}$$

As we were saying the operation carried out between $(1)$ and $(2)$ is not formally correct, but even accepting $(2)$ as granted the following last step remains for me a mystery: **for some reason unknown to me** we can now state that

$$\lim _{T \to +\infty}\frac{4 \sin^2 (\Delta E T/2)}{(\Delta E)^2}=(2\pi)T\delta (\Delta E)\tag{3}$$

and so finally

$$\delta ^2(\Delta E)=\frac{T}{2\pi}\delta (\Delta E) \tag{4}$$

**My question of course is:** how do we derive (3)? Why is it valid?

In answering please keep in mind that this question is asked by somebody with limited to non existing knowledge on distribution theory, and I also suspect that an answer to this question may be particularly useful to people with such a limited mathematical background; so please don't take to much as granted.

---

*[1]* If you want more context on this you can check out [this previous question on Math S.E.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814073/fourier-representation-of-diracs-delta-function)

Comment: (3) has $T$ on the RHS, while the limit $T\to\infty$ was taken on the LHS - is there a typo?

Comment: It's because the function $4 \sin^2(\Delta ET/2)/{(\Delta E)}^2$ integrates to $2\pi T$ when integrated from $\Delta E = -\infty$ to $\Delta E = +\infty$.

Comment: The distribution theory version of the step from (2) to (3) is essentially as follows: the statement
$$
\lim _{T \to +\infty}\frac{4 \sin^2 (\Delta E T/2)}{(\Delta E)^2}=(2\pi)T\delta (\Delta E)
$$
really means that for every "test function" $f$, we have
$$
\lim_{T \to \infty}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{4 \sin^2 (\Delta E T/2)}{(\Delta E)^2}f(\Delta E)\,d\Delta E = 2 \pi T f(0),
$$
which (by the definition of the $\delta$ function) is equal to $\int_{\Bbb R}2 \pi T\,\delta(\Delta E)f(\Delta E)\,d\Delta E$.

Comment: @user8268 There is no typo

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks a lot, your comment really helped me. Would you be so kind to expand it into an answer? I think it would help a lot of people in the future

Comment: @Noumeno I wouldn't say that I've answered the question, and I don't know that I can. Also, the first comment has a point: the left hand side of (3), assuming that the limit exists, should not be a function of $T$. However, the right hand side is dependent on $T$. So, something must be wrong. Analogously, an equation like
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} 2n = 2n
$$
would make no sense. Perhaps there are two different variables that you are referring to as both being "$T$".

Comment: @BenGrossmann I see the problem, indeed I am also baffled by the presence of T on the RHS in (3), but I can confirm this is indeed the result that we use in QED to deal with the square of the Dirac delta, so something strange is indeed happening

Comment: "We use"? I'm sure you are misreading your text. Chapter and verse reference?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Oscillatory_integrals).

Comment: @Noumeno this is a gentle reminder to accept an answer if your question has been resolved ;)

Comment: @Sal Hi there, unfortunately I don't get your explanation, that's why I didn't accept the answer, I was hoping some other clarification was on the way. The main problem for me is that I don't get what an "approximation to the identity" is, or how it works. If you could expand your answer to include some context it would be really great!

Comment: No problem- I added some explanation and changed my notation to be consistent with the wiki page. Let me know if it makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick **any** absolutely integrable function $\eta(x)$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  dx \ \eta(x)=1 $. We use $\eta$ to 'construct' a Dirac delta (a so called nascent delta or [approximation to the identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function?useskin=vector#nascent_delta_function) )

$$\tag{1}
\frac{1}{\epsilon}\eta\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right) \to \delta (x) \qquad ,\qquad \epsilon \to  0
$$

Where in the first expression $\to$ means in the sense of distributions. Concretely this means

$$\tag{2}
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\ 
\epsilon^{-1}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \eta(x/\epsilon) f(x)=f(0)
$$

For any suitable test function $f(x)$. Note that (2) is exactly the action of the delta: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \delta(x)f(x)=f(0)$. To prove (1) you can look at [theorem 9.8 in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1156948/865701).

Now we apply (1) to your question. Let $T=1/\epsilon$ then (1) reads

$$\tag{3}
T \eta(xT)\to\delta(x) \qquad , \qquad T\to\infty
$$

In your case we pick $\eta(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\sin^2(x/2)}{x^2}$ so that

$$\tag{4}
T\eta(xT)=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\sin^2(xT/2)}{x^2T}\to\delta(x) \qquad,\qquad T\to\infty
$$

So we have the equivalency

$$\tag{5}
\frac{4\sin^2(xT/2)}{x^2}\to2\pi T\delta(x) \qquad ,\qquad T\to\infty
$$

Just like (2), the expression in (5) means concretely that

$$\tag{6}
\lim_{T\to\infty} T^{-1} \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \left[\frac{4\sin^2(xT/2)}{x^2} \right]f(x) = 2\pi f(0)
$$

Note that I moved the $T$ to LHS so that the limit expression makes sense. The freedom to choose any suitable $\eta$ is very useful for 'picking out' Dirac deltas in various complicated expressions.